# React-Native: cannot update a component while rendering a different component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I've got this simple component Login:

```
function Login() {
  const [isFormValidState, setIsFormValidState] = React.useState(false);
  const [credentialState, setCredentialState] = React.useState();

  function getFormErrors(errors: any, dirty: boolean) {
    setIsFormValidState(!Object.keys(errors).length && dirty);
  }

  function getFormValues(values: any) {
    setCredentialState(values);
  }

  function doAction() {
    //credentialState rest call...
  }

  return (
    <View>
      <Text>Login</Text>
      <UserCredentialForm getFormValues={getFormValues} getFormErrors={getFormErrors}/>
      <Button title='Entra' disabled={!isFormValidState} onPress={doAction}/>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Which calls UserCredentialForm:

```
export default function UserCredentialForm({ getFormValues, getFormErrors }) {
[...]
  return (
    <Formik innerRef={formRef} validationSchema={formSchema} initialValues={state.form} onSubmit={() => { }}>
      {({ handleChange, values, touched, errors, dirty }) => {
        getFormValues(values);
        getFormErrors(errors, dirty);
        return <React.Fragment>
          // <TextInput/>....              
        </React.Fragment>
      }}
    </Formik>
  );

[...]
}
```

While navigating in my app I've got this error:

> react native cannot update a component Login while rendering a
> different component Formik.

Then it points me to the error in the `setCredentialState` inside `getFormValues` handler in Login component.
I've resolved this using a ref instead of a state, but the problem itself is unsolved to me.

What if I need to update my parent component view after a child event?

Comment: Did you have a look at this? https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/18178

Comment: @Stophface yes I did. It's  a discussion about the stack trace, not about How to solve the problem itself..

Answer (score 2):

The reason for that error is because you call `setState` inside `render()`. The call `getFormValues(values)`, which set the state of `credentialState` is called inside the render.

When the state is set, the `Login` component get rerendered, thus recreating a new function of `getFormValues`. As this is used as the prop of `UserCredentialForm`, it also causes that component to rerender, which causes the render prop inside `Formik` to calls again, which calls `getFormValues` causing the state change, causing an infinite loop.

One solution you can try is to add [useCallback](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback) to the two functions, which prevent them to have new identities after the state changes and consequently change the props, thus creating infinite rerender.

```js
function Login() {
  const [isFormValidState, setIsFormValidState] = React.useState(false);
  const [credentialState, setCredentialState] = React.useState();

  const getFormErrors = useCallback(function getFormErrors(errors: any, dirty: boolean) {
    setIsFormValidState(!Object.keys(errors).length && dirty);
  }, []);

  const getFormValues = useCallback(function getFormValues(values: any) {
    setCredentialState(values);
  }, []);

  function doAction() {
    //credentialState rest call...
  }

  return (
    <View>
      <Text>Login</Text>
      <UserCredentialForm getFormValues={getFormValues} getFormErrors={getFormErrors}/>
      <Button title='Entra' disabled={!isFormValidState} onPress={doAction}/>
    </View>
  );
}
```

However, there is still an issue and that is the identity of `values` may not be stable and by setting it to state, it will keep causing rerender. What you want to do is to tell `UserCredentialForm` not to rerender even when that state changes, and since the state is not used as a prop in `UserCredentialForm`, you can do that with [React.memo](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html).

```js
export default React.memo(function UserCredentialForm({ getFormValues, getFormErrors }) {
[...]
  return (
    <Formik innerRef={formRef} validationSchema={formSchema} initialValues={state.form} onSubmit={() => { }}>
      {({ handleChange, values, touched, errors, dirty }) => {
        getFormValues(values);
        getFormErrors(errors, dirty);
        return <React.Fragment>
          // <TextInput/>....              
        </React.Fragment>
      }}
    </Formik>
  );

[...]
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you got an unlimited loop of rendering,

you setState by getFormValues and the Login component re-render make UserCredentialForm re-render too, so it call getFormValues again and again

You can call getFormValues(values) in a useEffect hook after values of formik update

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `getFormValues` and `getFormErrors` inside a callback provided by Formik, that means you cannot wrap them inside an effect hook to suppress this warning or it will violate [rules of hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html).

I faced the same issue in React JS and got rid of it by using the following: approach.

I used [useFormik](https://formik.org/docs/api/useFormik) hook as an alternate.

and afterwards I refactored Formik form into a new component from where I made state changes to parent component.
This way I neither violated rules of hooks nor got this warning.

Also in the that newly refactored component you might need [useFormikContext](https://formik.org/docs/api/useFormikContext) and [useField](https://formik.org/docs/api/useField)

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar error while using reactNativeNavigation,

I had a TouchbleOpacity with an onPress event handler that navigates to a different screen

however I had it written like this ...

```
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={navigation.navigate("OtherScreen")}>...
```

which obviously calls the function to execute even though it hadn't been Touched yet

So I corrected it this way...

```
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=> navigation.navigate("OtherScreen")}>...
```

which doesn't call the function.

This answer is for people who may experience similar errors, even though the code has nothing to do with settingState

Answer (score -1):

Simple example can be like

UserCredentialForm:

```
 // Formik x React Native example
 import React from 'react';
 import { Button, TextInput, View } from 'react-native';
 import { Formik } from 'formik';
 
 export const MyReactNativeForm = ({onSubmit}) => (
   <Formik
     initialValues={{ email: '' }}
     onSubmit={values => onSubmit(values)}
   >
     {({ handleChange, handleBlur, handleSubmit, values }) => (
       <View>
         <TextInput
           onChangeText={handleChange('email')}
           onBlur={handleBlur('email')}
           value={values.email}
         />
         <Button onPress={handleSubmit} title="Submit" />
       </View>
     )}
   </Formik>
 );
```

Usage like

```
function Login() {

  function doAction(values) {
    console.log(values);
    //credentialState rest call...
  }

  return (
    <View>
      ....
      <UserCredentialForm onSubmit={doAction} />
      ....
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: Sorry, did you read my question? How this can help?